# Печать документов java

Tags: java

Мне надо распечатать файл, который хранится на локальном диске, но с такими параметрами: количество страниц, выбор цвет/чорно-белый принт. Вот что у меня есть:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(file_path));
```

Проблема в том, что таким способом печатается весь файл на дефолтном принтере(черно-белая печать).

Нашел что-то связано с печатью в пакете `java.awt.print`, но как создать объект файла что нужно напечатать не могу понять.

Comment: Уточните, какие файлы вы хотите печатать?

Comment: txt, docx , pdf

Comment: Смотрите сразу на библиотеки, типа [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j).

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такой вот способ печати да и добавление атрибутов:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
aset.add(new PageRanges(1,5));
PrintService[] services =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(myFormat, aset);
if (services.length > 0) { 
    DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob(); 
    try { 
        job.print(myDoc, aset); 
    } catch (PrintException pe) {}  
}
```